# HTML/CSS Visualizing a RBAC Graph

Tags: php, html, graphics, data-visualization, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a RBAC structure stored in my database (a project built with Yii).

I would love to generate a graph to visualize the relationships between the items to see if I'm not making logical mistakes, and to show to other team members.

I was thinking to create a page that would generate a graph / tree. I think I can handle the server-side part but I have no idea how to generate the HTML/CSS (or image).

Nodes in the graph can have multiple children and multiple parents. Arrows are directed. Example: [image: example]

I don't mind using latest CSS3 and HTML5 tech since it will be only used by selected people.

Comment: Can you try with the pear package ?

Comment: You may use http://sigmajs.org/ library too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into similar concerns a while ago. The solution I finally came with is a little js library that perfectly did the trick, namely Dracula.

Here is a link to the library : https://github.com/strathausen/dracula

Considering your needs, all you'll have to do is something like :

```
var g = new Graph();

g.addEdge('author', 'create');
g.addEdge('author', 'reader');
g.addEdge('author', 'admin');

// add here the other edges.

var layouter = new Graph.Layout.Spring();
layouter.layout();

var renderer = new Graph.Renderer.Raphael('#canvas', g, 400, 300);
renderer.draw();
```

For more infos, I'll let you struggle with the documentation.

Hope it helps.

[ADDENDUM]

I would add that, generally speaking, the matter of displaying nodes and arrows is not of a big deal, using svg makes it near trivial. But things get complicated when you want to organize the display of the nodes with rules such as "try to minimize the number of crossing edges", "display children below their parent", etc which all need complex mathematics.

I don't think that Dracula allows one to customize that kind of rules. Nevertheless, considering your comment, I think there may be a not-too-complicated way to make the layout looks like vertical tree, since it is an acyclic graph ( at least, it seems to be ). But then you will have to go through the making of your own library for this.

Comment: I've been playing with this, it's good. Documentation is non-existent and therefore hard to understand. I managed to create something half decent. The hard part is to make the layout look like vertical tree similar to the example.

Answer (score 1):

What about using **SVG**? SVG can be styled by CSS, accessed by Javascript and embedded in HTML documents. And using a vector format seems to be adequate for Graph visualization as it has many advantages. Just one advantage - especially in web environment - is the smaller file size of large graphs compared to bitmap images.

For the graph visualization itself, **[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)** comes in mind. It is a graph rendering software / library that has been actively developed since 1988. It is able to render various types of graphs and export the resulting image to various image formats including **SVG**. It uses the so called 'dot language' to describe graphs. Have a look at the Graphviz [project page](http://www.graphviz.org/) to find many examples and documentation on the dot language.

Do you have experimented with `dot` on the command line yet? `dot` is a binary from the Graphviz package that reads files written in the dot language and renders them to the desired image format. It is a good starting point for experiments.

I have once used it for drawing PHP class diagrams dynamically. I've generated a .dot file in php and translated it to SVG using `exec dot -Tsvg graph.dot`

There's also a PHP wrapper library for GraphViz in the PEAR repositories called [Image_Graphviz](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz/redirected) that is used in similar projects as yours.

Of course you'll have to make some layout compromises if you are working with a generic graph drawing library comparing to drawing them manually. But when going familiar with the dot language you'll achieve best results.

Answer (score 1):

***Just try with the following.,***

Graphs are one of the most frequently used data structures,along with linked lists and trees. In a recent PHP project I needed to build a Graph structure to analyze some interlinked urls. The problem was of a simple nature, so rather than writing my own code, I went with the one available in the Pear repository.

The Pear Structures_Graph package allows creating and manipulating graph data structures. It allows building of either directed or undirected graphs, with data and metadata stored in nodes. The library provides functions for graph traversing as well as for characteristic extraction from the graph topology.

Also refer the following location : http://www.codediesel.com/algorithms/building-a-graph-data-structure-in-php/

**Some Sample Codes :**

```
<?php

require_once 'Structures/Graph.php';
require_once 'Structures/Graph/Node.php';

$nonDirectedGraph = new Structures_Graph(false);

$nodes_names = array('a', 'b', 'c' ,'d', 'e');
$nodes = array();

foreach($nodes_names as $node) {
    /* Create a new node / vertex */
    $nodes[$node] = new Structures_Graph_Node();

    /* Add the node to the Graph structure */
    $nonDirectedGraph ->addNode($nodes[$node]);
}

/**
  * Specify connections between different nodes.
  * For example in the following array, 'a-b'
  * specifies that node 'a' is connected to node 'b'.
  * Also refer to the figure above.
  */

$vertices = array('a-b', 'b-c', 'b-d', 'd-c', 'c-e', 'e-d');

foreach($vertices as $vertex) {
    $data = preg_split("/-/",$vertex);
    $nodes[$data[0]]->connectTo($nodes[$data[1]]);
}
?>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you explained a method of building the graph STRUCTURE, while I am really looking for a way to display it to the user...

Comment: ya sure definitely you can do this...if you understood 'Structures_Graph'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Python on the server side, you could use [Networkx](http://networkx.github.com/) to generate high-quality graphics and save them as SVG, PNG or whatever you like.